# Canonical transformations including time

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

The canonical transformations conditions are equivalently:

$$\{Q^i,Q^j\}=0, \{P_i,P_j\}=0, \{Q^i,P_j\}=\delta_{ij}$$

$$\text{or}$$

$$dP_i\wedge dQ^j=dp_i\wedge dq^j.$$

But I think none of them include time transformations.  $Q=\lambda q$, $P=p/\lambda$ is canonical, but one may want to check some transformation that also includes time, e.g. $Q=\lambda q$, $P=p/\lambda$, $t^\prime=\lambda t$.

Is there any condition for a canonical transformation that includes the time variable?

Comment: you can always consider an extended phase space where $t$ is one of the canonical coordinates.

Comment: And the Hamiltonian is then it's conjugate variable.

Comment: I see, I can try doing that, but it feels strange to me because I haven't seen such treatment done in any textbook. I would like to see an example of this. If you have any source it would be appreciated.